# sending half value on mail

Tags: php

When I submit the form, the field values start with the home address. Half of the field values are not being sent.

First name, last name, area, phone, email are not being sent in the mail.

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$area = $_POST["area"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$street1 = $_POST["street1"];
$street2 = $_POST["street2"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$state = $_POST["state"];
$zip = $_POST["zip"];
$new = $_POST["new"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$already = $_POST["already"];
$time = $_POST["time"];

if($_POST["email"]){
    $ToEmail = 'info@example.com';
    $EmailSubject =' Example Title';
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"];
    $MESSAGE_BODY .=' First Name : '.$fname."\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .=' Last Name : '.$lname."\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .=' Phone Number : '.$area.' '.$phone."\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .=' Email : '.$email."\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .=' Home Address : '.$street1.' '.$street2."\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .=' City : '.$city."\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .=' State : '.$state."\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .=' Zip : '.$zip."\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .=' Looking for new service : '.$new."\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .=' Already have service with another provider : '.$already."\r\n";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .=' Select the best time : '.$time."\r\n";


    $MESSAGE_BODY .= 'Service Interested in :'."\r\n";
    if (isset($_POST['servicelist']) && !empty($_POST['servicelist']))        {
        foreach($_POST['servicelist'] as $selected ){
            $MESSAGE_BODY .= $selected."\r\n";
        }
    }
    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die     ("Failure");
    echo "Your message was sent";
    header("refresh:2; url:index.php");
}
else{
    echo "Sorry , No mail was sent";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're not using `PHPMailer`, you're just using the built-in `mail()` function.

Comment: You don't need to use both `isset()` and `!empty()`. `empty()` performs its own `isset()` check first.

Comment: how to resolve this

Comment: but the issue in name, mobile and email fields

Comment: Are you sure all those variables are set correctly? What does `var_dump($fname, $lname);` show?

Comment: That was just a general comment about `isset()`, not related to the problem.

Comment: Do you see the line `First name:` in the email with no value, or is that whole line missing?

Comment: yes i'm sure all varible are set correctly.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any typo where `.=` is just `=`. That will remove all the earlier fields.

Comment: Does `echo $MESSAGE_BODY;` show all the fields?

Comment: yup  $MESSAGE_BODY; show all fields

Comment: When you receive the message, check the raw source, do you see the missing fields there?

Comment: yes i see the missing fields there

Comment: So the fields are being sent, but you can't see them when reading the email. Are you using web-based email like Gmail to read email? Maybe there's HTML formatting that's causing the problem. Can you send an email to barmar@alum.mit.edu with this?

Comment: ok i send the file

Comment: I didn't want you to send me your code, I wanted you to run the script and make it send me a sample email.

Comment: I mean change `info@example.com` to my email.

Comment: please ty yourself bcs i don't have server detail

Comment: I tried it and I got all the fields. So your server must be doing something to the message.

Comment: 2 other random possibilities:  1)  change the line `$MESSAGE_BODY .=' First Name : '.$fname."\r\n";` to `$MESSAGE_BODY =' First Name : '.$fname."\r\n";` to make sure that there is no variable-initialization problems.  2)  since you are losing all the info at and prior to the email line, make sure that the `$email` variable doesn't have any undesirable characters in it (like, a quotation mark)